# How to add such that only zeros are filled leaving non-zeros unaffected in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, addition

I am trying to add a downshifted version of one image to to original and I want to add two images such that the zeros are filled leaving the non-zeros unaffected. I tried the following. Thanks for help in advance!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Given image
img1 = np.uint8(np.array([[0,  0,  0, 0],
                         [0, 10, 10, 0],  
                         [0, 20, 20, 0],
                         [0,  0,  0, 0]]))
#Target image: extend the lowest row of the non-zero region by an interger number of pixels(eg. 1 pixel)
img_target = np.array([[0,  0,  0, 0],
                       [0, 10, 10, 0],  
                       [0, 20, 20, 0],
                       [0, 20, 20, 0]])

#Tried this method but this does not work
img1_shiftdown=np.roll(img1,1,0)

img3=cv2.bitwise_or(img1,img1_shiftdown)
```

Comment: at least to me, it's not clear what you mean by "I want to add two images such that the zeros are filled leaving the non-zeros unaffected." suggest you clarify or add an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the last row to be a copy of the second to last row this code will work.

```
>>> img1 = np.uint8(np.array([[0,  0,  0, 0],[0, 10, 10, 0],  [0, 20, 20, 0],[0,  0,  0, 0]]))
>>> img1[-1]=img1[-2]
>>> img1
    array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
           [ 0, 10, 10,  0],
           [ 0, 20, 20,  0],
           [ 0, 20, 20,  0]], dtype=uint8)
```